# Check that after all inputs have value make button active

Tags: javascript

I want to remove the disabled attribute from the button when each field is filled out.
My code works when a single input is filled.
What am i doing wrong here?

Here are the HTML and JS

```js
checkInput()

function checkInput() {
    let input = document.querySelectorAll('.form-control')
    const button = document.querySelector('.submit-btn')

    input.forEach(function (e) {
        let disabled = true;
        e.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
            if (e.value !== '') {
                disabled = false
            } else {
                disabled = true
                return false
            }

            if(disabled) {
                button.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
            } else {
                button.removeAttribute('disabled')
            }
        })
    })
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">Name*</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="lastName">lastName*</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="lastName">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="fiscalCode">fiscalCode*</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="fiscalCode" placeholder="fiscalCode">
</div>
<button type="submit" disabled="disabled" class="submit-btn">Continue</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not work because you want to have all inputs affect the state of a button, yet you only check one variable for adding/removing disabled property.

Here is a working code snippet with an example where i created an array of properties, one for each input, that i can refer to in every fired key up event

```js
checkInput()

function checkInput() {
    let input = document.querySelectorAll('.form-control')
    const button = document.querySelector('.submit-btn')
    const disabled = Array(input.length).fill(true);

    input.forEach(function (e, index) {
        e.addEventListener('input', function () {
            disabled[index] = e.value === ''; // simplified if/else statement of yours

            if(disabled.some(Boolean)) {
                button.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
            } else {
                button.removeAttribute('disabled')
            }
        })
    })
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">Name*</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="lastName">lastName*</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="lastName">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="fiscalCode">fiscalCode*</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="fiscalCode" placeholder="fiscalCode">
</div>
<button type="submit" disabled="disabled" class="submit-btn">Prosegui</button>
```

Additionaly stoping the function execution when assigning disabled = true in the first else statement is also a wrong approach, as you most likely want to not only assign the disable value, but also the disabled property of the button.

EDIT: as mentioned in the comment by CID it is reasonable to change the event listener to input so we can handle the copying and pasting events as well

Comment: I would change the event listener from `keyup` to `input`, in the case the user right click -> paste

Comment: What would be the right approach if i were to add a checkbox?

Comment: just create a separate variable storing the checked value of the checkbox, or add checking that property to the button property change statement

Answer (score 2):

You are adding a keyup event for each input field.
that event only checks the current input field if it is empty or not.
it does not check the 3 input fields itself

this should do the trick:

```
checkInput()

function checkInput() {
    let input = document.querySelectorAll('.form-control')
    const button = document.querySelector('.submit-btn')

    input.forEach(function (e) {
        let disabled = true;
        e.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
           const emptyFields =  Array.from(input).filter( input => input.value === "");
           disabled = emptyFields.length > 0;
            if(disabled) {
                button.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
            } else {
                button.removeAttribute('disabled')
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: What would be the right approach if i were to add a checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

1. You are enabling the submit button on `keyup` event of any 3 inputs. So it gets enabled on any 3 inputs.
2. Remove the `return` on disabled flow to disable button after clearing.

```js
checkInput()

function checkInput() {
    let input = document.querySelectorAll('.form-control')
    const button = document.querySelector('.submit-btn')

    input.forEach(function (e) {
        let disabled = true;
        e.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
            if (e.value !== '') {
                disabled = false
            } else {
                disabled = true
                // return false <-- this makes function exit before your disable button
            }
            if(disabled) {
                button.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
            } else {
                button.removeAttribute('disabled')
            }
        })
    })
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">Name*</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="lastName">lastName*</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="lastName">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="fiscalCode">fiscalCode*</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="fiscalCode" placeholder="fiscalCode">
</div>
<button type="submit" disabled="disabled" class="submit-btn">Continue</button>
```

Comment: the `return` will exit the callback of the event listener, not the called function with a loop

Comment: @Cid yes, He also wanted to disable if user clears any particular selection. That code will only enable the button on any one field input, and will not disable again if user clears it out.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to check if all inputs are filled out on every change in any input.

```js
addHandlers();

// Return true if all fields are not empty
function areAllFieldsFilledOut() {
    let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.form-control');
  let result = true;
  
  inputs.forEach(e => {
    if (e.value === "")
        result = false;
  });
  
  return result;
}

// Add keyup event handlers to all input fields
function addHandlers() {
    let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.form-control');
    const button = document.querySelector('.submit-btn');

    inputs.forEach(e => {
        // On each change in any input, check if all inputs are
        // not empty, and if true, enable the button
        e.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
            let result = areAllFieldsFilledOut();

            if (result) {
                button.removeAttribute('disabled');
            } else {
                button.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">Name*</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="lastName">lastName*</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="lastName">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="fiscalCode">fiscalCode*</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="fiscalCode" placeholder="fiscalCode">
</div>
<button type="submit" disabled="disabled" class="submit-btn">Prosegui</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer:

```
function checkInput() {
    document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(input => {

        input.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
            let emptyFieldsCount = Array.from(input).filter(input => input.value == "").length;
            
            if (emptyFieldsCount > 0) {
                button.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
            } else {
                button.removeAttribute('disabled')
            }

        })

    });
}
```